# How get image from remote file?

Tags: php, image

Good day.

I insert in page INDEX.PHP image with help code:

```
<img src="/image.php?com=farm&id=4602">
```

CODE IMAGE.PHP:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: image/*");

$image = '/images/no_image.png';

$filename = basename($image);
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

switch( $file_extension ) {
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    default: $ctype="image/png";
}

// echo $image; // 
//echo $file_extension; will be image/png
 header('Content-type:'.$ctype);
 readfile($image);

}

?>
```

but i cann get image.

on page INDEX.PHP i see:

[image]

Anyone know where error?

Comment: that's surely the path issue. You should recheck your relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with absolute path. Maybe could help ;)

```
$image = 'http://yourdomain/images/no_image.png';
```

OR

**[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)** you have nice Example #1